# Weierstrass form for some equation

Tags: elliptic-curves

How to find a birational transformation that turns the equation $3(y^2-1)=2x^2(x^2-1)$ into Weierstrass form? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you can expand all terms and divide by $3$ to get

$$
y^2 = \frac{2}{3}x^4-\frac{2}{3}+1
$$

Then you can readily apply Theorem 6 from

http://homepage.uconn.edu/alozano/info/constrECrank_ALM.pdf

to get

$$
v^2 = u^3 - \frac{2}{3}u^2 - \frac{8}{3}u + \frac{16}{9}
$$

with

$$
u = \frac{2(x-\frac{2}{3})}{y}, v = -1+\frac{u^2x}{2}
$$

According to Sage the elliptic curve has rank $2$ and $2$ torsion points.

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: The article has moved to here: http://alozano.clas.uconn.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/490/2014/01/constrECrank_ALM.pdf